# Read query string parameters in Spring REST API (POST)

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

My Spring REST API is decorated as follows:

In below, I am confused weather, parameters such as `list`, `operation` need to be part of Url as query string or do they need to be part of Request Body as form data (Url encoded).

There are situations where I am sending these parameters in query string and it works fine. But couple of my api's are not working properly on production and they work only if I send the data in request body as Url encoded. Can anyone help me explain this behaviour ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bulkupdate/{companyId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<String> bulkupdateArticle(@RequestParam("list") String documentIdList,
      @PathVariable("companyId") String companyId, @RequestParam("operation") String operation){
      try{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the resource I find that it could be better designed in a more REST-ful fashion. I don't like to see POSTed data in the reside in the url.

Next to becoming more Rest-ful it would also make live for you much easier.

I would create a Data Transfer Object and pass it as the body of the POST request to your resource/spring controller.

Going from your data:

```
public class ArticleToUpdate {
    private String list; // list of what ? Maybe design it like List<String> somethingMoreMeaningFull
    private String operation;

    // .. getters
}

public ResponseEntity<String> bulkupdateArticle(@RequestBody ArticleToUpdate articleToUpdate) {
    // .. do whatever you need with the posted data
```

Now you can post a JSON or XML document in the body which will probably life much easier.

Additionally you could also add validation on the posted data through @Valid support now.